# html file loading differently from the browser then from text editor vs code

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have an issue with html file not compiling as it should when opening it directly on the browser. However, from vs code running Watch Sass and selecting Go Live compiles everything perfectly. Does anyone have encountered this type of issue. I will attach screenshots to demonstrate it and some code.

Opened from text editor

[image: 1]

Opened with browser

[image: 2]

```js
function openNav() {
    document.querySelector(".overlay").style.display = "block";
  }
  
  function closeNav() {
    document.querySelector(".overlay").style.display = "none";
  }
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300&display=swap");
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.overlay .close-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
}

.overlay h2 {
  font-family: "Alata", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin: 2rem 0 0 2.2rem;
}

.overlay .menu-toggle {
  margin: 10rem 0 0 2.2rem;
}

.overlay .menu-toggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 1.5rem;
}

.hero-img {
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../images/desktop/image-hero.jpg");
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .hero-img {
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("../images/mobile/image-hero.jpg");
  }
}

.hero-img .navbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 4rem 15rem 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .hero-img .navbar {
    padding: 2rem 2rem 0 2.2rem;
  }
}

.hero-img .navbar h2 {
  font-family: "Alata", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.hero-img .navbar .hamburger-menu {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .hero-img .navbar .hamburger-menu {
    display: block;
    height: 1.6rem;
    width: 2rem;
  }
}

.hero-img .navbar .menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: end;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .hero-img .navbar .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

.hero-img .navbar .menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 0.8rem 0 0;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.hero-img .navbar .menu a:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.hero-img .title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10rem;
  left: 15rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid white;
  padding: 1.5rem 6rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .hero-img .title {
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
    left: 2.2rem;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 11rem;
    color: white;
  }
}

.hero-img .title .header {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .hero-img .title .header {
    display: none;
  }
}

.hero-img .title .header-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .hero-img .title .header-mobile {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  }
}

.about-container {
  margin: 10rem 15rem 0;
  height: 42rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .about-container {
    margin: 4rem 2.2rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 42rem;
  }
}

.about-container .interactive {
  width: 40rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .about-container .interactive {
    display: none;
  }
}

.about-container .interactive-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .about-container .interactive-mobile {
    display: block;
    width: 20.6rem;
  }
}

.about-container .text-box {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5rem 0rem 5rem 5rem;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 18rem;
  left: 30rem;
  width: 35rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .about-container .text-box {
    width: 20rem;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 0rem;
    padding: 3rem 0 0;
  }
}

.about-container .text-box h2 {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .about-container .text-box h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
  }
}

.about-container .text-box p {
  font-family: "Alata", sans-serif;
  color: dimgray;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container {
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
  }
}

.container .flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  padding: 0 15rem;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: end;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container .flex-container {
    display: none;
  }
}

.container .flex-container h2 {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.container .flex-container button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 0.1rem solid dimgray;
  padding: 0.2rem 2.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  font-family: "Alata", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
}

.container .header-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container .header-mobile {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }
}

.container .cards {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (3fr)[4];
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 3fr);
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  margin: 0 15rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container .cards {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 2.2rem;
  }
}

.container .cards .card {
  width: 14.75rem;
  height: 26rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container .cards .card {
    width: 20.5rem;
    height: 7.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.container .cards .card .img-desktop {
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
          filter: brightness(50%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container .cards .card .img-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}

.container .cards .card .img-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container .cards .card .img-mobile {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
            filter: brightness(50%);
  }
}

.container .cards .card h3 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 5.6rem;
  left: 2.3rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container .cards .card h3 {
    bottom: 4.5rem;
    left: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.container .btn-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container .btn-mobile {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container .btn-mobile button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.1rem solid dimgray;
    padding: 0.2rem 2.2rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    font-family: "Alata", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    height: 2.2rem;
  }
}

footer {
  padding: 3rem 15rem;
  background-color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer {
    padding: 2rem 0;
  }
}

footer .top-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer .top-container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

footer .top-container h2 {
  font-family: "Alata", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer .top-container h2 {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
}

footer .top-container .icons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: end;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer .top-container .icons {
    display: none;
  }
}

footer .top-container .icons a {
  margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
}

footer .top-container .icons a img {
  width: 1.3rem;
}

footer .top-container .icons a:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

footer .bottom-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer .bottom-container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

footer .bottom-container .menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer .bottom-container .menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

footer .bottom-container .menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 0.8rem 0 0;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer .bottom-container .menu a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
  }
}

footer .bottom-container p {
  color: #8c8c8c;
}

footer .bottom-container .icons-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer .bottom-container .icons-mobile {
    display: block;
    margin: 2rem 0 1rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer .bottom-container .icons-mobile a {
    margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  footer .bottom-container .icons-mobile a img {
    width: 1.3rem;
  }
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <title>Frontend Mentor</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="hero-img">
    <div class="navbar">
      <h2>loopstudios</h2>
      <img class="hamburger-menu" onclick="openNav()" src="/images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="hamburger menu">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Careers</a>
        <a href="">Events</a>
        <a href="">Products</a>
        <a href="">Support</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <h1 class="header">IMMERSIVE<br>EXPERIENCES<br>THAT DELIVER</h1>
      <h1 class="header-mobile">IMMERSIVE<br>EXPERIENCES<br>THAT<br> DELIVER</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="overlay">
    <img class="close-icon" onclick="closeNav()" src="/images/icon-close.svg" alt="close icon">
    <h2>loopstudios</h2>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <a href="">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="">CAREERS</a>
      <a href="">EVENTS</a>
      <a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
      <a href="">SUPPORT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-container">
    <img class="interactive"src="/images/desktop/image-interactive.jpg" alt="A man wearing VR">
    <img class="interactive-mobile"src="/images/mobile/image-interactive.jpg" alt="A man wearing VR">
    <div class="text-box">
      <h2>THE LEADER IN<br>INTERACTIVE VR</h2>
      <p>Founded in 2011, Loopstudios has been producing world-class virtual reality 
        projects for some of the best companies around the globe. Our award-winning 
        creations have transformed businesses through digital experiences that bind 
        to their brand.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <h2>OUR CREATIONS</h2>
      <button>SEE ALL</button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="header-mobile">OUR CREATIONS</h2>
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-desktop" src="/images/desktop/image-deep-earth.jpg" alt="planet earth">
        <img class="img-mobile" src="/images/mobile/image-deep-earth.jpg" alt="planet earth">
        <h3 class="card-title">DEEP<br>EARTH</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-desktop" src="/images/desktop/image-night-arcade.jpg" alt="arcade">
        <img class="img-mobile" src="/images/mobile/image-night-arcade.jpg" alt="arcade">
        <h3 class="card-title">NIGHT<br>ARCADE</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-desktop" src="/images/desktop/image-soccer-team.jpg" alt="boy playing soccer">
        <img class="img-mobile" src="/images/mobile/image-soccer-team.jpg" alt="boy playing soccer">
        <h3 class="card-title">SOCCER<br>TEAM VR</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-desktop" src="/images/desktop/image-grid.jpg" alt="car">
        <img class="img-mobile" src="/images/mobile/image-grid.jpg" alt="car">
        <h3 class="card-title">THE<br>GRID</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-desktop" src="/images/desktop/image-from-above.jpg" alt="road">
        <img class="img-mobile" src="/images/mobile/image-from-above.jpg" alt="road">
        <h3 class="card-title">FROM UP<br>ABOVE VR</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-desktop" src="/images//desktop/image-pocket-borealis.jpg" alt="nothern lights">
        <img class="img-mobile" src="/images/mobile/image-pocket-borealis.jpg" alt="nothern lights">
        <h3 class="card-title">POCKET<br>BOREALIS</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-desktop" src="/images/desktop/image-curiosity.jpg" alt="machine">
        <img class="img-mobile" src="/images/mobile/image-curiosity.jpg" alt="machine">
        <h3 class="card-title">THE<br>CURIOSITY</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-desktop" src="/images/desktop/image-fisheye.jpg" alt="fish eye">
        <img class="img-mobile" src="/images/mobile/image-fisheye.jpg" alt="fish eye">
        <h3 class="card-title">MAKE IT<br>FISHEYE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-mobile">
      <button class="btn-mobile">SEE ALL</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="top-container">
      <h2>loopstudios</h2>
      <div class="icons">
        <a href="">
          <img src="/images/icon-facebook.svg" alt="facebook icon">
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="/images/icon-twitter.svg" alt="twitter icon">
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="/images/icon-pinterest.svg" alt="pinterest icon">
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="/images/icon-instagram.svg" alt="instagram icon">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Careers</a>
        <a href="">Events</a>
        <a href="">Products</a>
        <a href="">Support</a>
      </div>
      <div class="icons-mobile">
        <a href="">
          <img src="/images/icon-facebook.svg" alt="facebook icon">
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="/images/icon-twitter.svg" alt="twitter icon">
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="/images/icon-pinterest.svg" alt="pinterest icon">
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="/images/icon-instagram.svg" alt="instagram icon">
        </a>
      </div>
      <p>&copy; 2021 Loopstudios. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you opened the console in the browser to check for error messages? It looks like the browser can't find the files and images that you're able to see locally.

https://support.monday.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002197259-How-to-Open-the-Developer-Console

Comment: clearly the html is loading but not the css

Comment: yes in the console there's a lot of errors Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. However, how come it can't find when I have the in the local folder?

Comment: RESOLVED, I removed / from the css path <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">